# Change color of a tag of Android HTML?

Tags: android, textview

I've show a link on `TextView` with default color:

```
String htmlText = "<a href=\"SomeLink\">" + "SomeLink" + "</a>";
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

It's ok, then i try to add property color to a tag but it not working:

```
String htmlText = "<a style=\"color: #a6499a\" href=\"SomeLink\">" + "SomeLink" + "</a>";
```

`htmlText` log: `<a style="color: #a6499a" href="SomeLink">SomeLink</a>`, this working fine on browser.

Comment: How you exactly want to display?

Comment: I want to display a link with `#a6499a` color

Comment: Add android:textColorLink="yourcolorhere" to your TextView

Comment: Yep, many thanks, it's simpler than i think :).

Comment: if my Answer is helpful then accept my Answer :P

Comment: Not a good way to say thanks in stack you can mark correct or upvote answer if its really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this to your text view

```
android:textColorLink="#a6499a"
```

to your TextView and you will get color let me know if you face problem.

Regards.

Comment: This sets color only for the last link, not every link.

Answer (score 1):

use this it is working for me...

```
 String styledText = "Haven't received code yet? <font color='Blue'>Resend Code Click Here!</font>";
```

Comment: if you think my answer is useful then vote it as favourite answer so others can use it..

Answer (score 1):

try this code it's working...

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello World");
            ClickableSpan span1 = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View textView) {
                    // do some thing
                }
            };

            ss.setSpan(span1, 0, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setText(ss);
            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Use SpannableString it's easy and batter then HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

IF you wan to add a color programatically then you can do the following:

```
tv.setLinkTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: android:textColorLink="color"  can also be done in your xml file.

Comment: textColorLink not working on android 4.0.3. Please provide a new solution. Thanks